# Redirect new files in user folder on Windows

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a way to redirect files and folders that many programs are creating directly in the root of my user folder such as ".android" or ".gitconfig" to a different location. I know Windows has a built in virtualization tool for legacy software that writes to its program directory which throws files into AppData but I haven't seen any way to use that for myself.

There's a lot of visual noise in my user folder that I will never use directly so I'd like to hide it elsewhere. Hidden attribute won't cut it because I often do use hidden files directly and there's no difference between files I hid and files the system hid.

I am a programmer so I'm open to writing some kind of program if someone points me at an API that can do this.

Using Windows 10 specifically but this has been an issue on previous Windows versions too from bad ports/decisions.

Comment: These programs are probably ported from Linux, where the default for settings is the user's home directory. These configuration files all begin with `.`, and this excludes them from default directory listings and file expansions. You could see what the effect of changing `HOMEPATH` and `USERPROFILE` when running these programs, but there may well be a lot of unacceptable side-effects.

Comment: I think you might be thinking of the MS Application Compatibility Toolkit and the ability for shims to "fixup" older software.   Maybe Google for `CorrectFilePaths` in this context.  What OS are you on out of interest?

Comment: Whilst it might not be pretty, I guess you could `Symlink` them to a preferred location?

Comment: Symlink would still leave the icon in the user folder. It would not help my situation.

Comment: CorrectFilePaths would not work on a global or ongoing basis. Getting close with that one though, I will try to find some source/function calls on this to implement it myself for future files.